# Groups and Symmetries Question on permutations and cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let a=(123)(456) be in S10. If H is a cyclic subgroup of S10 and a is in H, what are all the possible orders of H?

My attempt: The order of a is 3 and the order of S10 is 10!. So we must find the greatest order b such that b^k = a for some k and then order of b <= order of H <= order of S10. Also H is cyclic so it can only take on even orders. Is this right? Please help! Thanks

Comment: The order of $S_{10}$ is $10!$.

Comment: isn't that the order of A10?

Comment: The order of $A_{10}$ is $\frac{10!}{2}$

Comment: What is $S$? If it's $S_{10}$ then that has way more than $10$ elements. Note that $a$ has order $3$, also, so that's the minimal size of a cyclic subgroup containing $a$. I think you want to investigate which elements in $S_{10}$ have some power equal to $a$. Maybe think about the powers of a single cycle $(i_1 \cdots i_r)$ first.

Comment: Your assumption that $|H|$ is between 6 and 10 is wrong; for instance if the element (789`10')(123)(456) belongs to the group, then this element has order 12 (hence 12 divides $|H|$)